Error with `copyfiles` command When Building Docker Image: failed with exit code 127
Description:
I'm facing an issue while building a Docker image for my frontend application based on the Payload CMS ecommerce template.
You can run npx create-payload-app to try installing ecommerce template. Let me know if you were able to build it.
Dockerfile:
I made modifications to the Dockerfile after repeatedly encountering a connect ECONNREFUSED error with the original one:
FROM node:18.8-alpine as base

WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package*.json ./

FROM base as builder
COPY . .
RUN yarn install

FROM base as runtime

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV PAYLOAD_CONFIG_PATH=dist/payload.config.js

WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package*.json  ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --production
COPY --from=builder /home/node/app/ .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "dist/server.js"]


docker-compose.yml:
I also made modifications to the docker-compose.yml for the same reason:
version: '3'

services:
 frontend:
   build:
     context: .
   ports:
     - '3000:3000'
   volumes:
     - .:/home/node/app
     - node_modules:/home/node/app/node_modules
   working_dir: /home/node/app/
   command: sh -c "yarn install && yarn build && node dist/server.js"
   depends_on:
     - mongo
   env_file:
     - .env

 mongo:
   image: mongo:latest
   ports:
     - '27017:27017'
   command:
     - --storageEngine=wiredTiger
   volumes:
     - data:/data/db
   logging:
     driver: none

volumes:
 data:
 node_modules:

package.json:
The package.json file is the same as the one in the Payload CMS ecommerce template:
"scripts": {
  "dev": "cross-env PAYLOAD_CONFIG_PATH=src/payload/payload.config.ts nodemon",
  "stripe:webhooks": "stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/stripe/webhooks",
  "seed": "rm -rf media && cross-env PAYLOAD_SEED=true PAYLOAD_DROP_DATABASE=true PAYLOAD_CONFIG_PATH=src/payload/payload.config.ts ts-node src/server.ts",
  "build:payload": "cross-env PAYLOAD_CONFIG_PATH=src/payload/payload.config.ts payload build",
  "build:server": "tsc --project tsconfig.server.json",
  "build:next": "cross-env PAYLOAD_CONFIG_PATH=dist/payload.config.js NEXT_BUILD=true node dist/server.js",
  "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production yarn build:payload && yarn build:server && yarn copyfiles && yarn build:next",
  "serve": "cross-env PAYLOAD_CONFIG_PATH=dist/payload.config.js NODE_ENV=production node dist/server.js",
  "eject": "yarn remove next react react-dom @next/eslint-plugin-next && ts-node eject.ts",
  "copyfiles": "copyfiles -u 1 \"src/**/*.{html,css,scss,ttf,woff,woff2,eot,svg,jpg,png,js}\" dist/",
  "generate:types": "cross-env PAYLOAD_CONFIG_PATH=src/payload/payload.config.ts payload generate:types",
  "generate:graphQLSchema": "PAYLOAD_CONFIG_PATH=src/payload/payload.config.ts payload generate:graphQLSchema",
  "lint": "eslint src",
  "lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .ts,.tsx src",
  "payload": "cross-env PAYLOAD_CONFIG_PATH=src/payload/payload.config.ts payload"
},

Issue:
I receive the following error log when building and running the Docker container:
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.35s.
yarn run v1.22.19
$ cross-env NODE_ENV=production yarn build:payload && yarn build:server && yarn copyfiles && yarn build:next
$ cross-env PAYLOAD_CONFIG_PATH=src/payload/payload.config.ts payload build
$ tsc --project tsconfig.server.json
$ copyfiles -u 1 "src/**/*.{html,css,scss,ttf,woff,woff2,eot,svg,jpg,png,js}" dist/
/bin/sh: copyfiles: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
demo-application$

Result of building:
funny part is it gets built; although frontend starts but stalls...
demo-application$ docker compose up -d --build
WARN[0000] /home/username/Documents/projects/demo-application/docker-compose.yml: `version` is obsolete 
[+] Building 156.2s (15/15) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                  docker:default
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                   0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 435B                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [frontend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18.8-alpine                                                                                                                    1.8s
 => [frontend internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [frontend internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                      2.5s
 => => transferring context: 4.50MB                                                                                                                                                             2.0s
 => [frontend base 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/node:18.8-alpine@sha256:8437bc872a71f3b15a384ff32d098a68e06b440c0d9ec3eb4b4fa26ca16f2b30                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [frontend base 2/3] WORKDIR /home/node/app                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [frontend base 3/3] COPY package*.json ./                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [frontend builder 1/2] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                             9.0s
 => [frontend builder 2/2] RUN yarn install                                                                                                                                                   118.4s
 => CACHED [frontend runtime 1/5] WORKDIR /home/node/app                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => CACHED [frontend runtime 2/5] COPY package*.json  ./                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => CACHED [frontend runtime 3/5] COPY yarn.lock ./                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => CACHED [frontend runtime 4/5] RUN yarn install --production                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => [frontend runtime 5/5] COPY --from=builder /home/node/app/ .                                                                                                                               10.9s 
 => [frontend] exporting to image                                                                                                                                                               5.8s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                         5.8s
 => => writing image sha256:8b8e1f110d888d915fc8de7a42edf6e0416c4f4b6cc4cdf65d40a5b453bfb403                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/demo-application-frontend                                                                                                                                    0.0s
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Container demo-application-mongo-1     Running                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 ✔ Container demo-application-frontend-1  Started                                                                                                                                               0.5s 
demo-application$ 

Containers:
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS                                           NAMES
e96c0357b5d7   demo-application-frontend   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   34 seconds ago      Exited (127) 14 seconds ago                                                   demo-application-frontend-1
a51909b3b5c5   mongo:latest                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes

.env:
# Run on a specific port
PORT=3000
# Database connection string
DATABASE_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017/demo-application
// and other config…

Additional Information:
The error occurs when trying to run the copyfiles command during the build process. It seems like copyfiles is not found, even though it is listed in the package.json and should be installed during the Docker build process.
I would appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Is copyfiles listed as a dependency or devDependency? I'd try setting it as a dependency if you haven't already.

I tried  devDependency to dependency, but i had the same error.  This payload cms template seems to be not buit.

can you try and build in the Dockerfile instead? I think that is the issue, because you are building in the docker-compose file
